# Différence entre « d'exercice » et « des exercices »

Tags: grammaire

Parmi les écritures suivantes laquelle est juste ?

1. Série d'exercices de révision
2. Série des exercices de révision

Quelle est la différence entre les deux ?

Answer (score 3):

Avec l'article indéfini, seule la première forme est possible: "je vous donne une série d'exercices de révision". L'autre forme "<strike>une série des exercices</strike>" serait complètement fautive.

Avec l'article défini, la première forme paraît plus naturelle: "je vous demande de faire la série d'exercices n°1 à 5", mais la deuxième est acceptable: "vous traiterez la série des exercices du jour".

Pour une utilisation sans article en guise de titre, "série d'exercices" ou "série des exercices" me semblent corrects tous les deux mais la première forme est plus habituelle.

Answer (score 1):

Tout dépend de où se trouve cette expression ; s'il s'agit d'un titre de section d'un chapitre contenant ces exercices on  utilise dans la plupart des cas « Série d'exercices de révision » ; « d' » est ici le partitif « de » après l'élision. On peut néanmoins considérer ces exercices comme quelque chose d'habituel, qui a été annoncé dans la préface par exemple en tant que section toujours présente à la fin des chapitres ; en ce sens il sont déterminés, ce sont **ces** exercices dont ont a été rendu conscient par la préface. On peut alors utiliser « Série des exercices de révision » puisque « **des** » est la contraction de « **de les** » et que « **les** » a un référent. On parle de ce cas en tant que cas justifié par une ([référence spécifique explicite](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/067.html)).  Il existe même la possibilité d'utiliser cette forme sans qu'un référent pour l'article défini ait été mentionné dans l'ouvrage et on parle alors de [référence spécifique implicite](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/067.html) ; il s'agit des exercices que l'on trouve habituellement dans un livre, comme par exemple lorsqu'on parle du téléphone que l'on trouve habituellement dans une maison (on dira, par exemple, « **Le** téléphone a sonné. »).

Si l'on trouve cette expression dans un texte les deux possibilités sont encore justifiables selon les mêmes principes mais il n'est plus question d'usage préférentiel indiquant l'utilisation du partitif, comme dans un titre.